# Comment traduit-on « lap » : cuisses ou genoux ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage

Est-ce qu'on dit

> placez l'enfant sur vos **cuisses**

ou

> placez l'enfant sur vos **genoux**

pour traduire « place the child across your lap » ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On dit « sur vos genoux » normalement.

Answer (score 1):

En Belgique et en France en tout cas, on dit « s'asseoir sur les genoux de quelqu'un ». À ne pas confondre avec « se mettre à genoux » qui consiste à mettre ses genoux au sol.

Answer (score 0):

Les traductions littérales *Placez l'enfant sur vos genoux* ou *Placez l'enfant sur vos cuisses* ne sont pas tout à fait correctes à l'oral en français (même si ce serait compris par tous).

Une phrase comme suit serait plus correcte :

> Asseyez l'enfant sur vos genoux.

Comment: On dit [asseyez](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/asseyez), pas [assaillez](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/assaillez).

Comment: Dire que les traductions sont incorrectes est exagéré, elles sont au pire peu idiomatiques. Rien ne dit d'ailleurs que l'enfant est forcément assis dans *place your child across your laps*, il pourrait aussi bien être couché si c'est un bébé.

Comment: @SteeveDroz : en effet, merci.